# json.cpp:474:23: fatal error: curl/curl.h: No such file or directory

Tags: ubuntu, package-management, curl, error-handling

I am trying to compile `ChatScript` but I get this error message:

> json.cpp:474:23: fatal error: curl/curl.h: No such file or directory

When I try `apt-get install curl` it says:

> curl is already the newest version (7.47.0-1ubuntu2.7).

I also tried to install `curl-devel` and `libcurl` but I get:

> E: Unable to locate package ...

Why this error happens and how can I fix it? I am using `Ubuntu-server 16.04 sunxi-arm7`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to install one of `libcurl4-gnutls-dev`, `libcurl4-nss-dev`, or `libcurl4-openssl-dev`, depending on which is appropriate (check ChatScript’s documentation and license; if the documentation doesn’t specify this, but the license has an OpenSSL license exception, use `libcurl4-openssl-dev`, otherwise try `libcurl4-gnutls-dev`).

In future, you can find this out by installing `apt-file` and using that:

```
apt-file search curl/curl.h
```

(The first time you install it, you’ll need to run `sudo apt-file update`.)